Исчезает текст в Rad Studio 11.3 Alexandria C++ builder
Есть данный код, который шифрует текст с помощью XoR, то есть делает это: сравнивает каждый бит первого операнда с соответствующим битом второго операнда. Если бит в одном из операндов равен 0, а бит в другом операнде равен 1, соответствующий бит результата имеет значение 1. В противном случае соответствующий бит результата равен 0. Один из пользователей ответил что происходил зануление так как когда одинаковые символы умножаются друг на друга получается 0. Можно ли найти какие то решения данной проблемы?
for (size_t i = 0; i < newText.size(); ++i) {
        ciphertext[i] ^= generatedKey[i]; // XoR
        procent = static_cast<int>(100.0 * (i + 1) / newText.size());
        Synchronize(&UpdateProgress);
        if(i > (ciphertext.size() - 15))
        {
        std::wstring wideCiphertext(ciphertext.begin(), ciphertext.end());
        Application->MessageBox(wideCiphertext.c_str(), L"Длина поля");
        }
      }

метод XoR реализуется в данном цикле с помощью символа ^. При попытке запуска с текстом :
Текст
Hello world! This message for check For me Hello world! This message for check For meHello world! This message for check For meHello world! This message for check For
Hello world! This message for check For me Hello world! This message for check For meHello world! This message for check For meHello world! This message for check For meaaaaaa
775267970K21S9
последние цифры являются контрольной суммы так как выполняется пункт 3.4.1. Ключ у данного кода получился такой.
Ключ
22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
пример исчезновения
Зашифрованный текст №1
zW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@?8zW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WSSSSSS?8267970K21S9
Посмотрите на конец текста
Зашифрованный текст №2
zW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@?8zW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WzW^^]E]@^VfZ[A_WAASUWT]@QZWQYt]@_WSSSSSS?8
`//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <System.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit2.h"
#include "Unit1.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

#pragma package(smart_init)
using namespace std;
string ciphertext;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//   Important: Methods and properties of objects in VCL can only be
//   used in a method called using Synchronize, for example:
//
//      Synchronize(&UpdateCaption);
//
//   where UpdateCaption could look like:
//
//      void __fastcall cipher_theard::UpdateCaption()
//      {
//        Form1->Caption = "Updated in a thread";
//      }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

string chooseGamma(string& text, string& numberShifr){

    if(numberShifr == "3.1.2." ||
    numberShifr == "3.2.4." || numberShifr == "3.2.5." || numberShifr == "3.2.6." ||
    numberShifr == "3.3.2." ||
    numberShifr == "3.4.2." ||
    numberShifr == "3.5.4." || numberShifr == "3.5.5." || numberShifr == "3.5.6." ||
    numberShifr == "3.6.1.4." || numberShifr == "3.6.1.5." || numberShifr == "3.6.1.6." ||
    numberShifr == "3.6.2.4." || numberShifr == "3.6.2.5." || numberShifr == "3.6.2.6." ||
    numberShifr == "3.8.1.4." || numberShifr == "3.8.1.5." || numberShifr == "3.8.1.6." ||
    numberShifr == "3.8.1.4." || numberShifr == "3.8.1.5." || numberShifr == "3.8.1.6.")
    {
        int latinCount = 0;
        int cirillicCount = 0;
        for (char c : text) {
            if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')) { // Подсчёт латинских символов
                latinCount++;
            } else if ((c >= 'А' && c <= 'Я') || (c >= 'а' && c <= 'я')) { // Подсчёт кириллицы
            cirillicCount++;
            }
        }
        string typeVariable;
        if(latinCount > cirillicCount)
        {
            typeVariable = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            typeVariable = '2';
        }

        numberShifr = numberShifr + typeVariable;

    }




    map<string,string> chooseShifr = {
    {"3.1.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.2.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.2.2.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.2.3.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.2.4.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.2.4.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.2.5.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.2.5.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.2.6.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.2.6.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.3.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.3.2.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.3.2.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.4.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.4.2.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.4.2.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.5.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.5.2.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.5.3.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.5.4.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.5.4.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.5.5.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.5.5.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.5.6.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.5.6.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.6.1.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.6.1.2.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.6.1.3.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.6.1.4.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.6.1.4.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.6.1.5.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.6.1.5.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.6.1.6.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.6.1.6.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.6.2.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.6.2.2.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.6.2.3.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.6.2.4.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.6.2.4.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.6.2.5.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.6.2.5.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.6.2.6.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.6.2.6.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.7.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.8.1.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.8.1.2.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.8.1.3.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.8.1.4.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.8.1.4.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.8.1.5.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.8.1.5.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.8.1.6.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.8.1.6.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.8.2.1.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.8.2.2.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.8.2.3.","3.1.1"},
    {"3.8.2.4.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.8.2.4.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.8.2.5.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.8.2.5.2","3.1.2.2"},
    {"3.8.2.6.1","3.1.2.1"},
    {"3.8.2.6.2","3.1.2.2"},
    };

    auto shifr = chooseShifr.find(numberShifr);
    string shiftStandart;
    if(shifr != chooseShifr.end()){
        shiftStandart = shifr->second;
    }
    else{
        shiftStandart=numberShifr;
    }

    map<string, string> cipherGamma = {
    {"3.1.1", "2"},
    {"3.1.2.1", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"},
    {"3.1.2.2", "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчщъыьэюя"},
    };

    shifr = cipherGamma.find(shiftStandart);
    string newGamma = shifr->second;

    return newGamma;
}


string chooseMarcant(string& numberShifr){
    map<string, string> chooseShifr = {
    {"3.2.1.","time"},
    {"3.2.2.","day"},
    {"3.2.3.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.2.4.","time"},
    {"3.2.5.","day"},
    {"3.2.6.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.5.1.","time"},
    {"3.5.2.","day"},
    {"3.5.3.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.5.4.","time"},
    {"3.5.5.","day"},
    {"3.5.6.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.6.1.1.","time"},
    {"3.6.1.2.","day"},
    {"3.6.1.3.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.6.1.4.","time"},
    {"3.6.1.5.","day"},
    {"3.6.1.6.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.6.2.1.","time"},
    {"3.6.2.2.","day"},
    {"3.6.2.3.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.6.2.4.","time"},
    {"3.6.2.5.","day"},
    {"3.6.2.6.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.8.1.1.","time"},
    {"3.8.1.2.","day"},
    {"3.8.1.3.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.8.1.4.","time"},
    {"3.8.1.5.","day"},
    {"3.8.1.6. ","dayWeek"},
    {"3.8.2.1.","time"},
    {"3.8.2.2.","day"},
    {"3.8.2.3.","dayWeek"},
    {"3.8.2.4.","time"},
    {"3.8.2.5.","day"},
    {"3.8.2.6.","dayWeek"},
    };
    string newMarcant;
    auto shifr = chooseShifr.find(numberShifr);
    string marcantStandart;
    if(shifr != chooseShifr.end()){
        marcantStandart = shifr->second;
    }
    else{
        newMarcant = "";
        return newMarcant;
    }
    time_t currentTime = time(nullptr);
    std::tm* localTime = std::localtime(&currentTime);
    if(marcantStandart == "time")
    {
        int seconds = localTime->tm_sec;
        Form1->Label1->Caption = "Секунда: " + IntToStr(seconds);
        if (seconds >= 0 && seconds < 20) {
            newMarcant = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
        }
        else{if (seconds >= 20 && seconds < 40) {
            newMarcant = "GHABOPIJMNCDKLEF";
        }
        else{
            newMarcant = "GHEFCDABOPMNKLIJ";
        }
        }
    }
    else{if(marcantStandart == "day")
        {
            char buf[64];
            strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", localtime(&currentTime));
            string dayStr(buf);
            int day = stoi(dayStr);
            Form1->Label1->Caption = "Число чётное: " + IntToStr(day);
            if(day % 2 == 0)
            {
                newMarcant = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
            }
            else
            {
                newMarcant = "GHEFABCDOPMNIJKL";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int dayOfWeek = localTime->tm_wday;
            map<int, string> week = {
            {0,"Воскресенье"},
            {1,"Понедельник"},
            {2,"Вторник"},
            {3,"Среда"},
            {4,"Четверг"},
            {5,"Пятница"},
            {6,"Суббота"},
            };

            auto chooseWeek = week.find(dayOfWeek);
            string nameOfWeek;
            if(chooseWeek != week.end()){
                nameOfWeek = chooseWeek->second;
            }

            Form1->Label1->Caption = "День недели: " + UnicodeString(nameOfWeek.c_str());
            if(dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 5)
            {
                newMarcant = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
            }
            else{if(dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 4)
            {
                newMarcant = "GHABOPIJMNCDKLEF";
            }
            else
            {
                newMarcant = "GHEFCDABOPMNKLIJ";
            }

            }
        }
    }

    return newMarcant;
}


string haveDlina(string& text, string& item){
    vector<string> shifr = {
        "3.3.1.", "3.3.2.", "3.5.1.", "3.5.2.", "3.5.3.", "3.5.4.", "3.5.5.", "3.5.6.", "3.7.",
        "3.8.1.1.", "3.8.1.2.", "3.8.1.3.", "3.8.1.4.", "3.8.1.5.", "3.8.1.6.",
        "3.8.2.1.", "3.8.2.2.", "3.8.2.3.", "3.8.2.4.","3.8.2.5.", "3.8.2.6.",};

        for (string& str : shifr) {
            if (str == item) {
                 text += to_string(text.size());
                 string textSize = to_string(text.size());
                 string sizeSize = to_string(textSize.size());
                 text += sizeSize;
                 return text;
            }
        }
        return text;
}


string haveKontrSum(string& text, string& item){
    vector<string> shifr = {
        "3.4.1.", "3.4.2.", "3.6.1.1.", "3.6.1.2.", "3.6.1.3.", "3.6.1.4.", "3.6.1.5.", "3.6.1.6.",
        "3.7.", "3.8.1.1.", "3.8.1.2.", "3.8.1.3.", "3.8.1.4.","3.8.1.5.", "3.8.1.6.",};

        for (string& str : shifr) {
            if (str == item) {
                int kontrolsumma;
                 for(size_t i =0; i<text.size(); i++)
                 {
                    kontrolsumma += (int)text[i];

                 }
                 string sizeSum = to_string(kontrolsumma);
                 text += sizeSum;
                 sizeSum = to_string(sizeSum.size());
                 text += "K21S";
                 text += sizeSum;
                 return text;
            }
        }
        return text;
}



string Main(string& text, string& trueGamma){

    string Key;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
        Key += trueGamma[i % trueGamma.size()]; // Генерируем ключ нужной длины
    }
    return Key;
}

__fastcall cipher_theard::cipher_theard(const string& text,const string& conventItem,bool CreateSuspended)
    : TThread(CreateSuspended), newText(text), newItem(conventItem),procent(0) {
    FreeOnTerminate = true;
}


    void __fastcall cipher_theard::Execute() {
    string marcant = chooseMarcant(newItem);
    newText = haveDlina(newText, newItem);
    newText = haveKontrSum(newText,newItem);
    string gamma = chooseGamma(newText, newItem);
    string generatedKey = Main(newText, gamma);
    ciphertext = newText;
    if(marcant == "")
    {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < newText.size(); ++i) {
        ciphertext[i] ^= generatedKey[i]; // XoR
        procent = static_cast<int>(100.0 * (i + 1) / newText.size());
        Synchronize(&UpdateProgress);
        if(i > (ciphertext.size() - 15))
        {
        std::wstring wideCiphertext(ciphertext.begin(), ciphertext.end());
        Application->MessageBox(wideCiphertext.c_str(), L"Длина поля");
        }
      }
    }
    else{
        string marcantKey  = Main(newText,marcant);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < newText.size(); ++i) {
            ciphertext[i] = newText[i] ^ generatedKey[i]; // XoR
            procent = static_cast<int>(100.0 * (i + 1) / (newText.size() + newText.size()));
            Synchronize(&UpdateProgress);
            if(i > (ciphertext.size() - 15))
        {
        std::wstring wideCiphertext(ciphertext.begin(), ciphertext.end()); // Преобразуем в wstring

        Application->MessageBox(wideCiphertext.c_str(), L"Длина поля");
        }
        }
        int procentDo = procent;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < newText.size(); ++i) {
            ciphertext[i] = newText[i] ^ marcantKey[i]; // XoR
            procent = procentDo + static_cast<int>(100.0 * (i + 1) / (newText.size() + newText.size()));
            Synchronize(&UpdateProgress);
        }
    }
}`

void __fastcall cipher_theard::UpdateProgress() {
    Form1->ProgressBar->Position = procent;
}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Что-то мне кажется, что у вас там получается 0, и строка при выводе обрезается. А вообще вопрос задан так, чтоб на него было практически невозможно ответить :) Не хотите посмотреть вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

@Harry вы оказались правы, так получается 0 и строка обрезается, можете ли подсказать решение данной проблемы?

Извините, но копаться в большой и длинной программе я не буду.  Тем более разбираться. как работает вывод в формах...

@Harry данная проблема состоит не в коде и не в выводе текста, а в том как работает данный символ ^, но всё равно спасибо, вы очень помогли

При шифровании xor-ом почти неизбежно получатся непечатные символы, в том числе и ноль. Так зачем вам выводить непечатное, как текст? Выведите, например, коды символов. Или закодируйте результат Base64.
